# fontspec error with Urdu in LuaLaTeX / XeLaTeX

Tags: errors, xetex, luatex, fontspec, unicode

This is my document with some Urdu text between English.

```
    \documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3} 
    \usepackage{xltxtra}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{urdu}
    \newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Jameel Noori Nastaleeq}  
    \begin{document}
    \title{Title goes here}
    \maketitle
    \section{Introduction}
    English text here \texturdu{ اردو ٹیکسٹ} English text here
    \end{document}
```

When I compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX it gives the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!
l.3530 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }

?
```

Comment: if you put that error message into this site's search you will find many answers including https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395163/error-in-fontspec  you need to use your package manager and update fontspec and expl3 to matching versions