# no support for greek script fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia, greek

I try to use a font (VAG-HurryPen), downloaded from [here](http://www.consider.gr/greek-free-friday-fonts-10/). However, when I compile my document using `XeLaTeX` engine, I get an error

> ! Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain
>   the Greek  script! (polyglossia)                Please define
>   \greekfont with \newfontfamily.

Here is the "language set up"

```
\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{VAG-HurryPen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
```

I tried to solve my problem following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24728/xelatex-with-polyglossia-and-greek) solution:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{VAG-HurryPen}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek]{VAG-HurryPen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
```

, but the problem still remains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be `\greekfont` not `\greekfontsf`. Also you can't specify `Script=Greek` because VAG-HurryPen does not have this OpenType script (even though it has the glyphs).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{VAG-HurryPen}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Mapping=tex-text]{VAG-HurryPen}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
\begin{document}
αβγδε
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `Mapping=tex-text` option should be `Ligatures=TeX`, but it's not needed because it's issued by default with `fontspec`.